DOM Xpath: select content between (invalid) use of nested <p><p> and </p></p> tags
I can't select the content of articles (that where made in Craft), I persume because of the invalid use by my former websitebuilder of double / nested P-tags in the HTML.
To clarify the code of the page:
<div class="col-sm-1"></div> 
<div class="col-sm-5"> 
  <h2>Title</h2> 
  <p><p>TEXT I WANT TO SELECT</p></p>
</div>

I have tried these selection methods:
//p
//p/*[first()]
//p[contains(text(),'')
//p[contains(text(),'')]//p


Please edit that into your question

Keep in mind that the parser will most likely convert this to <p></p><p>...</p>, same as the error correction in a browser would. https://3v4l.org/GQcsB

How about this:
//p//text()/parent::p

